# Compiling Ogitor with mingw

Tags: mingw, cmake, ogre3d

I'm compiling program (**Ogitor**) from source with **mingw**. The program compilation configure by **CMake** (use boost, ogre).

Last part of mingw32-make's log:

> .......
>   Info: resolving Ogre::Math::NEG_INFINITY      by linking to __imp___ZN4Ogre4Math
>   12NEG_INFINITYE (auto-import)
>   Creating library file: ..\lib\libOgitor_d.dll.a
>   c:/qt/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: warning
>   : auto-importing has been activated without --enable-auto-import specified on th
>   e command line.
>   This should work unless it involves constant data structures referencing symbols
>   from auto-imported DLLs.
>   **cd D:\Engine\Ogitor\v0-4-a\bin\Ogitor && copy "" ..\RunPath\bin
>
>   System can't find path.**
>   mingw32-make[2]: [lib/libOgitor_d.dll] Error 1
>   mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `D:/Engine/Ogitor/v0-4-a/bin'
>
>   mingw32-make[1]: [Ogitor/CMakeFiles/Ogitor.dir/all] Error 2
>
>   mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory`D:/Engine/Ogitor/v0-4-a/bin'
>   mingw32-make: [all] Error 2

The selected command is wrong. How I can repair it?

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
copy "" ..\RunPath\bin
```

probably indicates that a variable in the CMakeLists file used to create the copy command is empty.

In the CMakeLists file that does add_library(Ogitor_d ...) look for a custom command that uses "copy" and debug that file using CMake "message" commands to figure out what variable is empty. (Unless it's obvious from inspection. Maybe there's just a typo.)

Comment: I asked about this on official forum. Program's author said that MinGW no support temporarily and they recommended to use MSVC. Really, with MSVC project compiled without problems. May be if spend a lot of time we can build project with MinGW